Manually Building LLVM: libstdc++ version must be atleast 7.4
I am currently trying to install/build LLVM and MLIR on my machine, and have everything set up das suggested by LLVM/MLIR. This is the 'CMake' call I make:
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=mlir -DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON /
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="Native;NVPTX;AMDGPU" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON /
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON -DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD=ON /
-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER="Address;Undefined" -DMLIR_INCLUDE_INTEGRATION_TESTS=ON

But with this, I get:
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake:88 (message):
  libstdc++ version must be at least 7.4.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/config-ix.cmake:16 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:921 (include)

However, apt list --installed libstdc++\* reveals:
apt list --installed libstdc++\*
Listing... Done
libstdc++-10-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed]
libstdc++-11-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libstdc++6/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]

So I should at least have a higher version installed, but CMake either does not find it, or does not choose the right one. What could i be doing wrong? Other answers tried to softlink to newer versions, but that seems more hacky and unintended than anything.

It looks like LMIR ( libmlir-13, libmlir-13-dev ) along with the corresponding LLVM version are available from the Ubuntu 22.04 repositories - do you really need to build them from source?
